# can the value being calculated in a particular query be used in another query?

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I am calculating one parameter(X) this way:

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hand");

$result = mysql_query("select * from sessions",$link);
$num_calls = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo '<br/>'."\n Total X :\n $num_calls ".'<br/>';
?>
```

I am calculating another parameter(Y) this way:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hand");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE start_at > TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK, -4, CURDATE())  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_at, end_at) > 5");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo '<br/>'."\n Total Y :\n $num_rows ".'<br/>';
?>
```

At another place I need the to calculate the ration X/Y. How do I do that as it need to be done in another field in the same html page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do:

```
$num_calls = intval($num_calls); // Make sure these are integers
$num_rows = intval($num_rows);

$calculation = $num_calls / $num_rows;
echo $calculation;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I can't accept ur answer till a few mins...so i'll accept as soon the time is passed/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I *think* I understand.

You want X:Y where X is the ratio to Y:

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hand");

$result = mysql_query("select * from sessions",$link);
$num_calls_x = mysql_num_rows($result);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE start_at > TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK, -4, CURDATE())  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_at, end_at) > 5");
$num_calls_y = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo '<br/>'."\n Total X :\n $num_calls_x ".'<br/>';
echo '<br/>'."\n Total Y :\n $num_calls_y ".'<br/>';
echo 'Ratio: '.round(($num_calls_x/ $num_calls_y) * 100, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm
First that's a very expensive way of getting a count.

```
Select Count(*) from Sessions
```

and

```
Select Count(*) from Cars...
```

So something like

```
Select Cast(Select Count(*) From Sessions) as FLOAT) / (Select Count(*) From Cars...)
```

should get you close.

Then you don't need to bother persisting it, though if you insist, all the usual mechanisms apply.

Answer (score 1):

you could put the query strings into an array like this: 
    `$queryArray = array("select * from sessions", "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE start_at >
     TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK, -4, CURDATE())  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_at, end_at) > 5");` 
use a foreach just once:
    `foreach($query in $queryArray)
     {
         $result = mysql_query($query);
         $count = mysql_count($result);
         $countList[] = $count
     }`
     `$number = 0;`
and now you need to make the ratio out of the items from count with another foreach
    `foreach($number in $countList)
     {<br/>
         $number = $number + $number;
      }<br/>
     $ratio = $number / count($countList);`

Like this you can add all your future queries as strings and everything will still work.

P.S. I am unable to test the code at the moment but it should be quite functional. Not really sure about the foreach as.

Answer (score -1):

You can put this values to session/cookie and read it in another place.